# jQuery / JavaScript - prevent redirecting to file when downloading and renaming it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Soo when I download the file this way:

HTML:

```
<div data-dlxls="bla.xls" onclick="dlxls(this);">DL</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var xls = $(fil).data('dlxls');
window.location.href = 'xls/' + xls;
$("[data-dlxls='" + xls + "']").hide();
```

It works fine. The file downloads and that's it.

But when I move the file to another folder after it's downloaded through AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'movexlstoanotherfolder.php',
    type:'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {xls: xls}
});
```

I get redirected to the damn not any more existent file and see the damn 404 not found. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why would you use JavaScript to load a file to your Server that's already on your Server? If you already have the file on your Server, it's already there.

Comment: I need to put those files into "archived" after downloading them so I don't see them for downloading again

Comment: You want the Client *(Browser User)* to be able to only download it once, then disappear from your Server? I don't understand the question. Are you trying to make a random downloader?

Comment: Why do you need to know why I need that. I can think of many alternatives how to handle that. But this way would be the shortest. Ok ok people order stuff and what they order is saved into xls files in specific folder. I check with PHP for those files and my client can download them, after he download them they just need to be archived

Comment: The question is why the hell I get redirected AFTER the file is already downloaded by "redirecting"

Comment: Change the location on the Server, after the page name is changed.

Comment: I'm gonna do it by downloading the file after it was moved to archiv folder ^^